# Using Openblas with R in Reproducible R container

Tags: r, docker, openblas, liblas

I am using R for a reproducible scientific machine learing & hyperparameter optimizations. I stumble upon the fact that other implementations of blas such openblas/atlas/klm can speedup this costly  optimization. But results  are slightly different using each blas even if optimization is forced on single thread results deviate from default R.

So I want to try using [Docker](http://docker.com/) to contain the experiment. I have multiple questions.

1. is it good to compile from source instead of binaries ?
2. if I compile from source, will it lead to same configuration as debian binaries ?
3. since results are different for each blas, there is a tool called [ReproBLAS from Berkeley](http://bebop.cs.berkeley.edu/reproblas/),  is it good idea to use it with R ?
4. when you compile R using "--with-blas=-lopenblas" in this case openblas is single threaded or multithreaded ?

Comment: Do you really need results to be completely reproducible down to `x` significant digits? If your results can be reproduced to a reasonable level of precision and the conclusions are the same, I would think that would be good enough in a lot of cases. Then as long as you can explain the source of any differences (which I assume are fairly minor), people should be OK with that.

Comment: the problem is not being reproducible  to x digit but that x digit determine the value of the hyperparamter to be used...for example in randomforest openblas lead to 6 & 975 however reference blas(basic blas) lead 6 & 1000 for interaction depth & number of trees respectively....